# why is css coming from layout.css in nextjs

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIqx3.png)

this css styles is overriding my tailwind custom theme

I am customizing my font-family in tailwind.config.ts file like this

```
fontFamily: {
  sans: ['"PT Sans"', 'sans-serif']
},
```

but it is not applying

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You need to remove Inter fonts that you are importing using fonts/nextjs package in layout.jsx page. Only use any single way to import fonts.